# Android-How to log existing information without creating an application or service in android

Tags: android, logging, kernel

How do I log an existing information without creating an application or service(NO INSTALLATION OF ANY APP) in android. For example, if I wanted to log the connected wifi BSSID every minute without writing an application. I just want to log an already existing information. I wanted to create an inbuilt module sort of. I am ready to change the kernel or any layer and flash the phone. But I dont want an installation of an application that starts a service or anything of the sort. Would be great if you can give some suggestions or links and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You want to log existing information of apps you don't own or created?

This seems to be a complicated task. Your pretty much asking to decompile said APKs, adding some logging and then rebuilding.

Your best bet would be to learn about "adb logcat" via the Android Debug Bridge and hope that whatever you want to log is already being logged as this in my opinion is a big undertaking.

Comment: I dont want to log information of other apps. I just want to log information that is already getting stored in the proc file. I just want to log it every minute. There are already existing classes that gives this information.